# How to make a variable relationship?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Each Comment can be the child of either a Question, a Game, or a User. I designed the table so that it has two fields to manage the relationship, parent_type and parent_id. I do not understand how I would make this relationship work with CakePHP 2.1.. I know it is a belongsTo relationship, but how would I specify the table to which it belongs based on another field in that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments model

```
var $belongsTo = array(
                'Question' => array('className' => 'Question', 'foreignKey' => 'id'), 
                'Game' => array('className' => 'Game', 'foreignKey' => 'id'), 
                'User' => array('className' => 'User', 'foreignKey' => 'id'));
```

Questions model

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment', 
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id', 
        'conditions' => array('Comment.parent_type' => 'question')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html